# Make special function prototypes in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I was thinking about this... I know that you can do `Object.prototype.example()` but I was wondering how to do something like this: `ExampleFunction().prototype.exampleHandler`. Sort of like how this works:`document.querySelector().id` I think that it is possible. If you have any questions about it, please comment! 

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with prototypes? Do you think `.prototype` is special somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make something work like `document.querySelector().id` you just need to add a property to a function, and as functions are objects it's easy, or return an object with those properties when the function is called, like this

```js
var example = function(what) {
  return {
    id : what
  }
}

var foo = example('foo').id; // TADA

example.bar = function() {
    return {
      id : 'not foo'
    }
}

var bar = example.bar().id;

document.body.innerHTML = foo + ' - ' + bar;
```

And that's how chaining works in it's simplest form.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That seems so obvious now.